# while loop in credit card validation exercises - python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an assignment question I can solve using if/elif, but the question requires a while loop, and I am a bit lost.

> q:. A credit card number is valid if the sum of all digits is a multiple of 10. Write a program which accepts a 16 digit credit card number stored in a variable num,  Your program should also verify whether the user entered correct number of digits before validating the number.

I have:

```
num = raw_input("Please enter a credit card number: ")
total = 0
while len(num) == 16:
    for i in num:
        total = total + int(i)
    print total
    if total % 10 == 0:
        print "ok"
    else:
        print " not ok"
else:
    print " not long enough"
```

I can see why I get stuck in a never ending loop, and I can fix by getting rid of the while completely, but not sure how to fix my answer but still have a while loop the question requires.

Comment: Can you include the part where your assignment tells you to use a `while` loop? You now have two different interpretations of where to put such a loop, and the exact wording of your assignment could give us some clarification.

Comment: thanks very much guys...too answer you question is says the code should be:1) initialization. 2) while loop. 3) if.elif statements....so the while loop is the first thing after the initializations

Comment: I see no `for` loop mentioned there. :-) But it is a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if` instead of `while`:

```
if len(num) == 16:
    for i in num:
        total = total + int(i)
    print total
    if total % 10 == 0:
        print "ok"
    else:
        print " not ok"
else:
    print " not long enough"
```

You should not use a `while` loop for simple condition; `if` is far more suitable there.

You could use a `while` loop instead of the `for` loop though:

```
i = count = total = 0
while i < len(num):
    digit = num[i]
    i += 1
    if digit in ' -.':
        # spaces, dashes and dots are fine
        continue
    if not digit.isdigit():
        # Oops, not a digit, bail out, not valid
        break
    total += int(digit)
    count += 1

if count != 16 or total % 10 != 0:
    print "Not a valid credit card number!"
else:
    print "Ok"
```

This has the added bonus that you now accept spaces, dots and dashes in the credit card number too.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a flag say `valid` to `False` then `while not valid:` prompt the user for the number, sum the digits of the entered number and then set `valid` to `(len(number) == 16) and ((sum % 10) == 0)` no `if`s required.